# Stuck on an assertion involving floors of base-$10$ logarithms

Tags: logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How can I prove that the following statement is either true or false ?

$$\forall \space n, k \in \mathbb{N}^* \space \text{s.t.} \space (n+1)\lfloor \log n\rfloor-\frac{10}{9}(10^{\lfloor \log n\rfloor}-1) = kn, k = \lfloor \log n\rfloor-1$$
which is equivalent to: $$10^{k+1} \leq n < 10^{k+2}$$

(*N.B.* : $\log n$ is indeed the base-$10$ logarithm of $n$.)

Actually, it seems to be true, regarding the first values of $k$ and $n$ :

| Values of $k$ | Values of $n$ | Values of $\lfloor \log n\rfloor-1$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $1$ | $108$ | $1$ |
| $2$ | $1,107$ | $2$ |
| $3$ | $11,106$ | $3$ |
| $4$ | $111,105$ | $4$ |
| $5$ | $1,111,104$ | $5$ |
| $6$ | $11,111,103$ | $6$ |
| $7$ | $111,111,102$ | $7$ |
| $8$ | $1,111,111,101$ | $8$ |

and so on (notice the pattern describing $n$ first values). However, I have absolutely no idea how to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rearranging the condition
$$
(n+1)\left\lfloor\log_{10} n\right\rfloor
 - \frac{10}{9}\left(10^{\left\lfloor\log_{10} n\right\rfloor} - 1\right)
 = kn
$$

into this form:
$$
\left(\left\lfloor\log_{10} n\right\rfloor - k\right) n
 = \frac{10}{9}\left(10^{\left\lfloor\log_{10} n\right\rfloor} - 1\right)
 - \left\lfloor\log_{10} n\right\rfloor.
$$

Let $x = \left\lfloor\log_{10} n\right\rfloor.$
You have $x \in \mathbb Z$ and $x \geq 0$ (since $n$ is a positive integer).
Now for any such value of $x,$ solve for $k$ and $n$ in

$$
\left(x - k\right) n = \frac{10}{9}\left(10^x - 1\right) - x
$$

under the condition that $10^x \leq n < 10^{x+1}.$
Note that the condition $x \geq 0$ is necessary but not sufficient for there to be a solution with positive integers $k$ and $n.$

Comment: Well, I agree, but sorry I don't get how this could help me to show that $k$ is necessarily equal to $\lfloor \log_{10} n\rfloor -1$…

Comment: @Lava I wanted to leave **something** for you to do. For every $x$ there is at most one solution, and for that solution you can write $n$ and $k$ as functions of $x.$ We expect the solution for $k$ to be $\lfloor\log_{10} n\rfloor-1,$ but I suggest you consider the possible values of $n$ first.

Comment: Actually you don't really need to completely solve for $n.$ It's just that you can. You could, instead, merely prove that the right-hand side is less than $2\times10^x$ and use that to draw a conclusion about $x-k.$

Comment: Thanks. I showed $n(x-k) < 2 \times 10^x$ so $x-k<2$ with $x$ and $k$ positive integers. We want to prove that $x-k$ always equals $1$ ; with $x-k = 0$ we find $10 \leq n < 100$ and there is no such value of $n$ whatever $k$ is (but I don't know how to prove it). Also with $x-k <0$ we find $\frac{10}{9}(10^x -1) -x < 0$ – this must implies $x < 0$ and thus contradicts our definition of $x$ although I don't know how to show that too.

Comment: There are a few details that have to be ironed out for some of those small-number cases, and a full proof will be significantly longer than what I wrote. You can assume you choose a value of $x$ first and then find $k$. This is valid as long as you consider all possible values of $x.$ I think you will want to handle $x=0$ and $x=1$ each as a special case; your table shows the first few results for $x\geq2$. In addition to showing that that the right hand side is less than $2\times10^x,$ I see you also have to show that it is positive in the case $x \geq 2.$

Comment: Done. We've $x \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $u_n=\frac{10}{9}(10^n-1)-n$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$. We proved that $u_n<2 \times 10^n$; moreover it's easy to show that $u_n>0$. So: $0<u_x = n(x-k) <2 \times 10^x$.$n(x-k) <2 \times 10^x \Leftrightarrow \frac{x-k}{2} < 1 \Leftrightarrow x-k < 2$. Also $n(x-k) > 0$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ implies $x-k > 0$. As they are integers, the unique solution is $x-k = 1$. QED. Thank you.